# doing if statement with array element

Tags: arrays, perl, loops, if-statement

I have a string that repeats from 0 to 31 repeatedly called `$GRIBWORKLIST2[$i]` throughout the entire sequence of `$i` which goes all the way to 8,000 (`@GRIBWORKLIST == 8000`).

Whenever the value of `$GRIBWORKLIST2[$i+1]` is going to be 0 that means the values of `$GRIBWORKLIST2[$i]` completes a cycle and return to 0 again. For the output whenever this happens I want it to display

```
$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
```

Below is my attempt to do this.

Any ideas how to tweak this so it will give me the desired result?

```
for ( my $i = 0; $i < @GRIBWORKLIST; $i++ ) {

    if ( $i == ( @GRIBWORKLIST - 1 ) ) {

        print "----> ---> --> -> "
            . $GRIBWORKLIST[$i] . " | "
            . $GRIBWORKLIST2[$i] . " || "
            . $GRIBWORKLIST2[ $i - 1 ] . "\n";
    }
    else {

        print "----> ---> --> -> "
            . $GRIBWORKLIST[$i] . " | "
            . $GRIBWORKLIST2[$i] . " || "
            . $GRIBWORKLIST2[ $i - 1 ]
            . " |||  "
            . $GRIBWORKLIST2[ $i + 1 ] . "\n";

        my %q = $GRIBWORKLIST2[ $i + 1 ];

        print STDOUT "$q\n";

        if ( $q == 0 ) {
            print STDOUT "$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$\n";
        }
    }
}
```

This gives me the output:

```
Can't use string ("32289") as a SCALAR ref while "strict refs" in use at ...
```

Comment: Apart from the problem you have with interpolating `$$$` (`$$` is a built-in variable that contains the PID of your process, and the first `$` tries to dereference that as a reference to a scalar value) you need to change `my %q = $GRIBWORKLIST2[ $i + 1 ]` to `my $q = $GRIBWORKLIST2[ $i + 1 ]`. It's also very important that you `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` at the top of every Perl program you write, which would have revealed this error. There's very little point in declaring variables with `my` unless you have `use strict` in place

Answer (score 1):

`$$` has a meaning, see [perlvar](http://p3rl.org/perlvar). Use single quotes to avoid interpolation of dollars.

```
print STDOUT '$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$', "\n";
```